# How to clear first radio buttons textbox value by clicking on another radio button

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

I Have 2 radio buttons.on click first radio button textbox will open,when click on another radio button second textbox will open..now i want when i click on second radio button first radio buttons textbox should be clear.

> View :

```
<label>Assign Credit Limit Amount/Days</label><br>
<label for="chkYes">Credit Amount</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<label for="chkNo">Day</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
<div id="creditAmount" style="display: none"><br>
    <label for="creditAmount">Credit Amount</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="creditAmount" placeholder="creditAmount" name="creditAmount" maxlength="128">
</div>
<div id="day" style="display: none"><br>
    <label for="day">Day</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="day" placeholder="day" name="day" maxlength="128">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

> javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv() {
        var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes");
        var chkNo = document.getElementById("chkNo");
        var creditAmount = document.getElementById("creditAmount");
        creditAmount.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
        var day = document.getElementById("day");
        day.style.display = chkNo.checked ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on your requirement?

Comment: The simplest solution would be:
document.getElementById(id_of_textbox).value="";

Answer (score 0):

Add a if condition and for true, reset the value of the input:

```
if (chkNo.checked) {
      creditAmount.querySelector('input').value = '';
    }
```

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {
    var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes");
    var chkNo = document.getElementById("chkNo");

    var creditAmount = document.getElementById("creditAmount");
    creditAmount.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
    var day = document.getElementById("day");
    day.style.display = chkNo.checked ? "block" : "none";
    
    if (chkNo.checked) {
      creditAmount.querySelector('input').value = '';
    }
}
```

```html
<label>Assign Credit Limit Amount/Days</label><br>
                                <label for="chkYes">Credit Amount</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                <label for="chkNo">Day</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />

                                    <div id="creditAmount" style="display: none"><br>
                                    <label for="creditAmount">Credit Amount</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="creditAmount" placeholder="creditAmount" name="creditAmount" maxlength="128">
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="day" style="display: none"><br>
                                    <label for="day">Day</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="day" placeholder="day" name="day" maxlength="128">
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear the value of the input field using pure javascript you can use:

```
document.getElementById("creditAmount").value = "";
```

This will not work in your case because you have multiple `creditAmount` IDs in your HTML:

```
<div id="creditAmount" style="display: none"><br>
```

and

```
<input type="text" class="form-control amount-input" id="creditAmount" placeholder="creditAmount" name="creditAmount" maxlength="128">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add condition to track which button is clicked and what input text to be cleared.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function ShowHideDiv() {
 var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes");
 var chkNo = document.getElementById("chkNo");
 var creditAmount = document.getElementById("creditAmount");
 creditAmount.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
 var day = document.getElementById("day");
 day.style.display = chkNo.checked ? "block" : "none";

 # condition goes here to clear input value
 chkYes.checked ? creditAmount.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = "" : day.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = ""
</script>
```